# How to fix redirection from https//www to https//non-www version of website?

Tags: iis, https, redirect

I added ssl to iis last week and i configured redirect 301 rules in web.config of my website.

today i noticed that https://www version isn't redirected to https://non-www version of my website and resources like pictures and css files are available in both version of my website.

are these rules i added to my web.config correct?

Because of IIS and wordpress i had to add redirection of resources and Unicode Url to web.config.

redirection from http to https is working

redirection from http//www to http://non-www is working

but redirection from https//www to https://non-www is not working!

my web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="HTTPS" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" 
redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect Image to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|pdf|ttf|woff2|woff|mp4)$" 
ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
<serverVariables>
<set name="REQUEST_URI" value="{UNENCODED_URL}" replace="true" />
</serverVariables>
</rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you rules seem no problem then it seems that you want to realize that change any https request like https://www.example.com to https://example.com right? I have made a sample here. Here is the rule,I hope it could help you.

```
 <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www[.](.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```